# Google Chrome keeps opening at login even after turning 'open applications at login' setting off for Chrome in Big Sur

Tags: macos, google-chrome, big-sur

I'm only facing this issue in Big Sur as this problem didn't occur before in Catalina.
I'm currently using Mac OS version 11.0.1

Comment: Did you check if it's in the login items in `System Preferences`? 
 https://support.apple.com/en-nz/guide/mac-help/mh15189/mac

Comment: @Joonas Yes, I did. That's what I meant when I said 'open applications at login' setting. Apparently, it is named differently in the system preferences search bar.

Comment: Right... In that case, was it open when you closed the computer? (or logged out). And did you have `reopen windows when logging back in` option checked in the confirmation dialog that shows up when you're when shutting off the computer?

Comment: No it wasn't open when I closed the computer. I mainly use Safari. Also, I have that option turned off. Also, I'm pretty sure that this is a problem with Big Sur because when you install Chrome for the first time, it is set to open at login by default until you make the necessary changes in the `System Preferences`. I did the exact same thing in Catalina. I started facing this problem just after installing Big Sur.

Comment: Well I'm stumped... My next action, without any research, would probably be to reinstall it. Uninstalling should get rid of whatever causes it and it shouldn't end up in any startup items. I'd uninstall it using [this](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) or any other app like that. Or course it would get rid of your settings in that browser, but if you sync your settings...etc, there shouldn't be a problem. The last thing that comes to mind is making sure no third party apps launch it.

Comment: It's quite honestly been 7 years since I last installed Chrome on a mac... I had no idea it would set itself to open on startup on install. I'm not entirely sure I even believe that. It sounds a little too invasive, but if you say that's how it is, then I guess that's how it is. But maybe still try the reinstall?

Comment: Yeah, I too think that its a little too invasive. I only use Chrome because certain apps that just work well with Chrome and some that are incompatible with Safari. I'll try reinstalling it.